# Android: Many Edittexts in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

this is my getView method:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.propviewlistrow, null);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propviewlistrow_t1);
            holder.content = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propviewlistrow_e1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.content.setText(values.get(position));       
        holder.content.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {      
                values.set(position, s.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                    }

        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But this does not work.
The edittexts do not display the proper text, the displayed text switches while scrolling.
The next issue is, I have set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the manifest.
If you click the into the last edittext, the listview won't scroll up enough so that you can see what you are typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not answering your question directly, but if i were you i'd redesign that list.
It's gonna be major PITA for the user to use edit fields in the list. What i'd do - either use long-press action and bring dialog or dialog activity to edit, or use quick actions pattern

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html